# Physician's clerk confirmed 4 months, but then cancelled 1 week, before appointment because Physician "reached capacity". What are Patient's remedies?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

How can I make on topic [Physician's clerk confirmed 4 months, but then cancelled 1 week, before appointment because Physician "reached capacity". What are Patient's remedies?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/89561)? I authorize anyone to edit and improve it. Many thanks!

The two  oldest comments miss the point, and  the blindingly obvious fallout from physicians backpedaling like this. They unworkably assume that Canadians can walk right into a specialist's clinic any time to be seen! They ignore the reality of waiting a whole year to see specialists.

> [Sounds like a rant to me. Nobody here can do anything. Find another Cardiologist and move one.](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/41460/jwh20)

This accusation of rant is groundless! This comment ignores the CPSBC's by-laws, added to my post. I raise a legitimate issue.

> [Consider this problem in the other direction: The Clerk called the patient twice, and confirmed the appointment completely. Patient No-Showed. Can the Dr. sue the patient for lost time & wages? We would all be much better off not constantly looking to sue everyone and anyone, except in exceptional circumstances. Things come up, life is inconvenient, and you move on.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/89561/physicians-clerk-confirmed-twice-but-cancelled-just-before-patients-appointm#comment202098_89561)

This comment appears wrong. Yes, Canadian Drs. can sue the patient for lost time and wages. ["You may be charged for a missed appointment only if your physician has warned you about this in advance and has a cancellation process in place."](https://www.cpsbc.ca/public/public-resources/what-expect/charging-uninsured-services)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s a rehash of the question that was closed on the main site.

Comment: Yes I did, and if you leave at the top I will reopen. It’s all the stuff after that that is a rehash.

Comment: @DaleM Does it not assist to embody the closed submission in this question, so that readers can see what got closed ??? Still want me to delete the submission?

Comment: Leave a link, that’ll do

Answer (score 1):

### You ask for Legal advice - [that is not allowed here](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer)

You throw your life story at us and ask what your rights are. That's asking for legal advice and [not allowed on the stack](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer). If you want individual legal advice, go and get a lawyer. Free or cheap consultations are often available.

### You ask a way too broad set of questions

While related, that is **way** too broad for here, as the analysis for each of the questions could be a question on its own. The second question doesn't properly parse to what you want to have answered, and the third does not indicate where those items come from, besides asking an open-ended question of "what else".

### Wording and Tone

> The issue is blindingly obvious...

Your whole post is worded very accusatory and aggressive. That alone is a violation of the [code of conduct](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/conduct), which is not very complicated. Please re-read the code of conduct.